# How does bit.ly get the title of a pasted URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

It immediately populates after I enter in the URL and hit enter.  Are they downloading and parsing the page for the tag title or is there an easier way?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be instant for me. On my end (example link bit.ly/1c92v5e ) I don't see a change in the document title until the response from the URL I'm redirected to starts to be parsed by the browser.

Comment: If you follow the network trace for a bit.ly URL in the browser, it just gets back a 301 response with the redirect URL in a header and nothing related to the title at all.  So, the title isn't known until the redirected URL starts to load and the browser starts parsing that response.

Answer (score 2):

What bit.ly does is redirect the webpage to another webpage.

When you click on a bit.ly link an http request is sent to their server. The second part of the url will be in their database mapped to the original url. bit.ly then redirects you to the original page using a 301 redirect. A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect from one url to another. 301 redirects send site visitors and search engines to a different URL than the one they originally typed into their browser or selected from a search engine results page.

[This](https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/7430/what-is-a-301-redirect-and-why-should-you-care.aspx) is a link that states about 301 redirects and sites similar to bit.ly works